# Can you set the qDebug() floating point precision and number format globally?

Tags: c++, qt, number-formatting

I want to use qDebug(), qInfo() and so on with a custom default floating point precision and number format.

Is there a way to define this globally?

Imagine this:

```
double num = 1.2;
qDebug() << "My floating point Number is: " << QString::number(num, 'f', 2);
//Output: My floating point Number is 1.20
```

Now I would like to avoid QString::number(num, 'f', 2) everytime I write a number and would much rather like to use a standard percision and format.

Comment: It's not possible to change it globally (unless you are ready to change Qt sources and recompile them). The closest possible thing is to create your own alternative to `qDebug()` function and use it instead. You can redefine operator<< for floats and leave the rest unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.
`qDebug()`, `qFatal()`, etc... return instances of the class `QDebug`. 
The issue is that the operator `QDebug::operator<<(float f)` is a non virtual class member function.
You cannot define another without getting the compile error message

> operator<< is ambiguous

Answer (score 18):

Formatting of a `QDebug` stream [can be controlled](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#formatting-options) through [`QTextStream` manipulators](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#qtextstream-manipulators). Therefore, you must call

```
qDebug() << fixed << qSetRealNumberPrecision(2);
```

in the beginning of your program.

Note, however, that the formatting state of `qDebug()` may change later if some (not so carefully written) code sets required formatting and doesn't restore it to the previous state after completing its job.

**EDIT**

It turns out that the effect of `QTextStream` manipulators (at least in combination with `qDebug()`) is limited to the containing statement and doesn't persist. So, the best you can do is define your replacement of `qDebug()` as follows:

```
#define myqDebug() qDebug() << fixed << qSetRealNumberPrecision(2)
```

and use it instead of `qDebug()`:

```
double num = 1.2;
myqDebug() << "My floating point Number is: " << num << endl;
```

Output:

```
My floating point Number is:  1.20
```

Comment: you can do printf-style, too, on a per statement basis, e.g. `qDebug("my number is %.2f", num);`.

Answer (score 0):

`fixed` field determines that nine elements in the mantissa will be displayed (after point).

Example for printing array with 9 nums at all, in one line:

```
{
    QDebug debug=qDebug();
    for (const double val: values)
    {
        debug<< qSetRealNumberPrecision(9)<< val<< ',';
    }
}
```